# Closed Surface integrals and Gauss's Law

Tags: calculus, physics

I'm trying to understand Gauss's Law and I'm having some issue with understanding the notation.

I understand that $\oint_Cf(x)\cdot dx $ means taking the line integral on f(x) that ends at the beginning point.  My question is what does $\oiint f(s)\cdot dA $ mean?  Is it the sum of all possible closed line integrals across the surface or something else?

Also, does anyone know the Latex to get the \oiint to render on this?

Answer (score 0):

What this is stating is that taking the line integral over the closed path is the same as taking the integral over the area that has the path as a extreme points $C = \partial A$. But they are not the same type of integrals, one is a line integral and the other is *a integral over an area.*

This is what I understand of your question. This notation means that you should calculate the integral over the closed surface related to the closed path $C$.

---

MathJax doesn't support this symbol, so what you have is to use 'unicode'

> $$\Huge\unicode{x222F}f(s)\cdot \mathrm dA$$